# What have you found is the most effective way of training a Scrum Master?

Tags: scrum, agile, scrum-master, lean, agile-coach

I need to train someone to become a scrum master. I have read so many books and articles over the years and everything is really available online.

Thus far I have been having regular knowledge sharing sessions with him but the client wants me to formalise these sessions in some way...which is counter the agile manifesto I believe.

Anyway, I am thinking of putting together a powerpoint deck which I can list these resources and then also use the agile coaching institutes competencies as a heading for each slide. e.g. teaching, coaching, facilitating etc.

Has anyone else got any better ideas of A) how to train a scrum master and B) how I could structure a powerpoint deck.

There is just so much information I could include but I don't want to overwhelm him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Client wants formalised sessions then the best option is to go to a formal session from Scrum.org or ScrumAlliance.

https://www.scrum.org/courses

https://www.scrumalliance.org/courses-events/course

Both sites have a ton of resources for your slide deck.

Regards

Comment: Agreed. Going to a class taught by professionals could give you good ideas on how to approach this.

Comment: FYI, I just spoke to a scrumalliance.org vendor and they described the CSM course as a 2 day session with a nearly 100% pass rate.  It appears to be an introduction to the concept of scrum mastering, but is clearly not a challenging certification - which makes me (personally) question the actual value of the course.

Answer (score 1):

Read and understand the [Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

Read and understand [The Scrum Guide](http://scrumguides.org/).

Know the history and intent of the philosophy.

Seek further training: https://www.scrum.org/ founded by Scrum author after leaving Scrum Alliance for its shortcomings.